# Creating a route with two optional parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working with react router. Initially I two different components being rendered under the same route one with a parameter and one without(this is how the routes were differentiated). Now I am trying to add optional parameters to the first route while not editing the second one route. The issue is there is no way to tell the difference between the first route and the second.

For example:

Initially my routes looked like this:

```
<Route exact={true} path="/encounter-monitor" component={EncounterMonitor} />
<Route
    exact={true}
    path="/encounter-monitor/:encounterID"
    component={EncounterMonitorDetails}
/>
```

And with my update it now looks like:

```
<Route
   exact={true}
   path="/encounter-monitor/:queryData?"
   component={EncounterMonitor}
/>
<Route
    exact={true}
    path="/encounter-monitor/:encounterID"
    component={EncounterMonitorDetails}
/>
```

I tried editing the 2nd route name but this is causing issue for users on the site using links to the old paths. So I am trying to figure out if there is anyway to have two components rendered by the same route depending out the contents of the optional parameter? Or if theres a way to append an optional part of the route that is not a part of the query? for example I was trying something like this for the first route:

```
<Route
   exact={true}
   path="/encounter-monitor/search?/:queryData?"
   component={EncounterMonitor}
/>
```

Adding search as an optional part of the path but this doesnt work either. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this? I want the base route to always be `/encounter-monitor/`

Comment: There is no way to do it, you need to have a condition under a single route

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by condition? Or are you just saying each route has to be unique?

Comment: I mean you should have a single route, and inside the component which is rendered under this route, you write something like ```return condition ? <EncounterMonitor /> : <EncounterMonitorDisplay />```

Comment: `"/encounter-monitor/:queryData?"` and `"/encounter-monitor/:encounterID"` have the specificity so there's no way to differentiate them. Create a wrapper component that reads the path param, applies a conditional test and conditionally renders the correct routed component.

Answer (score 1):

if the parameters are different you can try using regex to validate the route

for example suppose your id is numeric and your query alphanumeric

```
<Route
    exact={true}
    path="/encounter-monitor/:encounterID([0-9]+)"
    component={EncounterMonitorDetails}
/>
<Route
   exact={true}
   path="/encounter-monitor/:queryData?"
   component={EncounterMonitor}
/>
```

that way if the parameter has only numbers you show a route if it contains letters and numbers you show another

you can do validation tests on

https://pshrmn.github.io/route-tester/#/

more examples

https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp